# Pegar textContent selecionado da combobox com javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Estou tentando pegar o textContent da combo na hora que for clicar no botão Salvar, para assim ele montar uma tabela com os valores digitados dos input text e da combo selecionada. Exemplo do html:

```html
<div class="modal-content" id="cadastro-tarefa">
<label class="" for="orderBy">Nome</label>
  <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="">
  <div class="form-group">
  <label class="" for="orderBy">Tipo</label>
    <select class="form-control cb" id="cb" name="meucombo">
      <option value="" disabled selected>Selecione</option>
      <option value="1">Pergunta e Resposta</option>
      <option value="2">Multipla Escolha</option>
      <option value="3">Grade de Multipla Escolha</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Você só quer pegar o valor digitado e o valor selecionado, é isso?

Comment: @arthur eu quero conseguir exibir numa tabela o valor de uma das 3 opções, seja Pergunta e Resposta, Multipla Escolha ou Grade de Multipla Escolha, eu quero poder exibir essa seleção na nova tabela, eu só to conseguindo pegar o value que é o 1,2 ou 3. Quero exibir os textos. É uma listagem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode pegar os valores definindo um `id` para os controls e pegando por `getElementById`. Veja se serve pra você

```js
document.getElementById('btSalvar').onclick = function () {
  var nome = document.getElementById('txtNome').value;
  var tipo = document.getElementById('cb').value;
  if(nome && tipo){
      console.log(nome);
      console.log(tipo);
      var cb = document.getElementById("cb");
      var selectedText = cb.options[tipo].text;
      var html = '<td>' + nome + '</td><td>' + selectedText + '</td>';
      var tabela = document.getElementById('resultado');
      tabela.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html);
  }
  
}
```

```html
<div class="modal-content" id="cadastro-tarefa">
<label class="" for="orderBy">Nome</label>
  <input id="txtNome" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="">
  <div class="form-group">
  <label class="" for="orderBy">Tipo</label>
    <select class="form-control cb" id="cb" name="meucombo">
      <option value="" disabled selected>Selecione</option>
      <option value="1">Pergunta e Resposta</option>
      <option value="2">Multipla Escolha</option>
      <option value="3">Grade de Multipla Escolha</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <br>
  <button id="btSalvar">Salvar</button>
</div>

<table id="resultado">
<th width="60px">Nome</th>
<th width="160px">Tipo</th>
</table>
```

Comment: @arthur é isso mesmo, mas em vez de trazer o "1", "2" ou "3" da combo eu queria que a combo trouxesse  "pergunta e resposta" ou "multipla escolha"ou "grade de multipla escolha"

Comment: @IsabellaMeirelles e agora?

Comment: @Arthur, é exatamente isso. Muito obrigada

Comment: @IsabellaMeirelles você pode aceitar minha resposta clicando no símbolo ali. Você também pode votar em qualquer resposta no site

Comment: @Arthur Adicionei, obrigada

Comment: @Arthur, eu tô aplicando essa solução no meu código, mas tá dando um erro na linha tabela.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html); erro: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'insertAdjacentHTML' of null Vc sabe o que pode ser?

Comment: @IsabellaMeirelles Sim. Você tem que criar a table com o ```id="resultado"```, como eu fiz ali

Answer (score 1):

Seria isso que você deseja fazer?

```js
jQuery(function($){
  $('#salvar').click(function(){
    var nome = $('#nome').val();
    var tipo = $('#cb').val();
    
    console.log(nome);
    console.log(tipo);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="modal-content" id="cadastro-tarefa">
<label class="" for="orderBy">Nome</label>
  <input class="form-control" id="nome" type="text" placeholder="">
  <div class="form-group">
  <label class="" for="orderBy">Tipo</label>
    <select class="form-control cb" id="cb" name="meucombo">
      <option value="" disabled selected>Selecione</option>
      <option value="Pergunta e Resposta">Pergunta e Resposta</option>
      <option value="Multipla Escolha">Multipla Escolha</option>
      <option value="Grade de Multipla Escolha">Grade de Multipla Escolha</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<input type="button" id="salvar" value="salvar">
```

Comment: Acho que ela não quer jQuery